# Regular Expression - At most One Repeated Digit

Tags: regex, computer-science, formal-languages

I am struggling with a homework problem. I have tried this problem for hours literally. I found a similar question here, but it is not exactly my problem.

The homework problem says 1. (20 points) Construct regular expressions for the following languages.
a) All strings of digits with at most one repeated digit.

The only way I see how this is possible would be to exhaustively somehow take care of every possible case. There are 10 different digits, so it's like A LOT of different cases. I think the max length string can be 11, because after 11, you have to have a second repeated digit. So the number of possible combinations is 10^11. I thought even about writing a DFA and just converting it to a regex, but even that seems like it's impossible.

Does anyone have any advice? We aren't allowed to use non-standard regex features, like groups, lookahead, etc. This is just a plain old regex kind of problem.

Response to comment:
It is not binary. I already asked the teacher.

"Commenters, “regular expression” has one well-defined meaning in computer science. Since this is homework, it’s almost certainly that which is meant (and even more so as it talks of “languages”), and not some specific library. There’s no ambiguity here, and no clarification needed." This is basically what we want. The standard regex stuff often used in theoretical CS classes. As far as what we learned in class, I go to USC if anyone is familiar with that and we only barely talked about this at all. We're onto a completely different topic now.

Comment: Does it say anything specific about decimal? If not, just assume it's binary.

Comment: At most one repeated digit is intended to mean consecutive digit?  Or just repeated anywhere?  The former is pretty easy, the latter would be difficult without backtracking.  IE, is 11212121212 acceptable, or not acceptable?  I could see 'repeated' to mean consecutive.

Comment: I wish it was binary. :) I actually asked the teacher if it was binary because I really couldn't figure out any possible way to do it.

Comment: Joe - It means repeated anywhere. I.e. 12341 is accepted, but 12131 is not

Comment: As there's no real "standard" for regexes, I'd like to know how one can determine what features are non-standard. (For example, grouping is *very* "standard")

Comment: We're not allowed to do things like (A) and then say \1. This isn't a programming problem. It's a HW problem about regular expressions.

Comment: Uh oh... [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506816/regular-expression-at-most-one-repeated-digit#comment32468734_21506893) "*Those features weren't covered in our class.*" suggests to me that this question cannot be answered... we have no idea what is and is not allowed because we've not been in your class!

Comment: POSIX EREs seems to match the closest.

Comment: Commenters, “regular expression” has **one** well-defined meaning in computer science. Since this is homework, it’s almost certainly *that* which is meant (and even more so as it talks of “languages”), and not some specific library. There’s no ambiguity here, and no clarification needed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - And if this were strictly a computer science website, then that could be easily assumed. But given that this is a programming language website, "regex" has a much broader, less pedantic meaning. Clarification is needed, as not all questions here deal with the "computer science" definition.

Comment: @JDB Like I said, the context makes this entirely unambiguous. The fact alone that the assignment says “Construct regular expressions for the following languages” pretty much clarifies what’s meant here. That said, I’ve added some relevant tags.

Comment: If it is not a programming question then it doesn't belong to Stackoverflow. It should be asked in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ probably.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science and theory. Stack Overflow is geared for professional or enthusiast programmers. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @anubhava - I think you picked the wrong site. You probably meant http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JDB: Yes my mistake, meant http://cs.stackexchange.com/. Thanks

Comment: "At most one repeated digit" is so ambiguous. In `111112345` only the digit `1` is repeated; so there is "only one repeated digit". Or you could say `12121212` has no digit "repeated" (since there are other digits in between). But it turns out Google is your friend. If you type "All strings of digits with at most one repeated digit" you will be taken to solutions of problem sets for a number of CS courses (Cornell, Chicago, …) Not that I would encourage getting that kind of homework help...

Comment: For this question, I think it is enough as long as you show the DFA. Constructing the RE is very tedious, since this basically tests for permutations of non-repeated digits.

Comment: Is 1x2x1x2 acceptible? Two digits are repeated, but only once.

Comment: @acarlon - this was [already addressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506816/regular-expression-at-most-one-repeated-digit#comment32468656_21506816).